# How to set a new value for auth()->guard('user')->id?

Tags: laravel-5

The following code,

```
$userData = auth()->guard('user')->user();
```

gives the user data. How can I set the value of a field from auth()->guard('user')?

Say something like this:- `auth()->guard('user')->fname = 'Test';` when `$userData['fname']` is empty.

Is it at all possible?

Comment: depending on the end-goal, you can get the user by doing: Auth::user(); Then you can update the name and save like so: $user = Auth::user(); $user->email = 'bla@bla.bla'; $user->save();

Comment: @RobBiermann Please can you add your above comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to change the array of user after extracting it to some variable and then use that variable further on like so:

```
$userData = auth()->guard('user')->user();
if (empty($userData['fname'])) {
    $userData['fname'] = 'Test';
}
//use $userData from now on for listing user details
```

However, if you really need to change the authorized user object itself, you will need to use "accessor" in laravel. Here is a [thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/add-a-new-attribute-in-authuser-session-in-laravel-53) to help you get that in detail.

*I hope it helps.*

Answer (score 0):

depending on the end-goal, you can get the user by doing: `Auth::user();` Then you can update the name and save like so:

```
$user = Auth::user(); 
$user->email = 'bla@bla.bla'; 
$user->save();
```